# Should we have just one Meta tag for topicality?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tags, meta

We currently have three Meta tags that relate to topicality:

- [scope](/questions/tagged/scope)
- [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic)
- [off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic)

A question about on-topicness or off-topicness (separately) are still about scope.  A general question about topicality could still use all three and even [site-policy](/questions/tagged/site-policy).  I've seen them used inconsistently sometimes, although that isn't quite so bad since the tags still fit properly.

Should we have one universal tag called, say, [topicality](/questions/tagged/topicality)?  If this is done, then the three listed tags could be synonymized or merged into the new one.

Comment: A Meta-meta question? Awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already proposed synonyms

- Master [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) ← Synonym [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic)
- Master [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) ← Synonym [off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic)

However, I doubt that anyone has score enough points for [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) to vote for approval.  If this answer gets sufficient upvotes, I'll manually approve it instead.

I considered a [topicality] tag, but it wasn't in use on Stack Overflow meta, so I didn't want to start doing something different.

I think this is the simplest solution that could solve the tag overlap problem.

Answer (score 4):

[off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic) has 24 questions, [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) has 10 questions, and [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic) has 29 questions and no tag wiki.

I don't see why we would need more than just one tag for this. They're all about the same thing really, and [9 questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on-topic+off-topic) are even tagged with both [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic) and [off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic)!

[site-policy](/questions/tagged/site-policy) has 69 questions, 13 with [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic), 10 with [off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic), 5 with both, and 2 with [scope](/questions/tagged/scope).

---

Now, [topicality](/questions/tagged/topicality) might be an appropriate term, but I haven't seen it used on any meta site.

MSE has 303 questions under [scope](/questions/tagged/scope), 430 under [off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic), and... a grand total of 0 for [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic).

---

Here's the MSE tag wiki for [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) (emphasis mine):

> [scope](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope) is used to define what is pertinent to discussion.
>   Generally, the scope determines what the site is about. Issues arising
>   from [scope](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope) **might have to do with whether a certain question is
>   on-topic or not, but also can be used to evaluate whether an entire
>   topic should be up for discussion** (especially as it pertains to
>   specific Stack Exchange sites).
>
> Using this tag indicates that the question is requesting help with
>   scope (normally as a specific use of a general topic), and answers
>   should generally relate to the scope of the site and whether the topic
>   raised generally relates. It also may be the case where a user has a
>   question, [but doesn't know where it belongs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62131/where-do-mediawiki-questions-belong).

Looks like it's *our definition* of "scope" that's too narrow.

Hence, I suggest we burn [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic), redefine [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) and retag [up to] 30 meta-questions (10+29-9) with [off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic), which becomes the new king of topicality questions, as it seems to be on the majority of SE sites.

Comment: This solution looks good.  I've found MSO's tag wiki for [off-topic], which states: *This tag is for questions regarding off topic questions, including whether a question is on topic and what to do with off topic questions.*  I suppose, in most cases here, [scope] won't even be needed.

Answer (score 2):

English Language & Usage calls their tag [[on-topic-off-topic]](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/on-topic-off-topic/info).  I think that name is clear and covers everything related to topicality and scope.